# What is the difference between a locator and a Webelement in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

In the documentation for [expected_conditions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html) in selenium the methods either take a webelement or take a locator. They are obviously quite similar, but what is the difference in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different.

A locator is nothing more than an abstract way of defining *how* an element will be found.

A `WebElement` is just the reference to that element within the DOM. It is `Selenium`'s way of representing a DOM element to you so that you can manipulate it.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly `webelement = browser.find_element_by_id('id_here')` is a webelement and a locator could be represented with the `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

Comment: @Jonathan to my best understanding - you are correct

Answer (score 1):

Locator is used to identify element. You can use it or if you have already created a element object you can use it.
If you pass element directly (if you have it) WebDriver willnot need to create a new object. If you pass locator WebDriver will use it to create Element object.
PS: I am not much familiar with Python.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by both of the other answerers. The locator is used to identify the actual element. Whereas the webelement is an object found. What does this look like in code?

The following gives you a webelement object. 
`webelement = browser.find_element_by_id('id_here')`

Whereas if you need to use a locator as described in the documentation you need to do the following. Example taken from [Explicit waiting](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebdriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement")))
```